# Want to compare one column with all others to find non zero values, in result count the number where both are non zero

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have about 24 columns in df. I want to compare one columns with all other to find where the values are non zero and count all non zero values. Here is how an example how df looks.

```
Col A   Col B    ColC
1         1       2
2         2       5
0         1       1
4         0       0
0         0       3
0         9       0
1         0       8
2         2       0
```

I want to see non zero values and then count and in the count of all where both columns are non zero. 
So i want that Col A first compare with B and then C.
Then col B with A and then C and so on...

I can write manually to one by one to compare. But i want to write a function where it do automatically.

Comment: Can you add expected output? Do you need `df['new'] = df.ne(0).sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: It should be a like (df(A and B) : 3 and all other comparison as a count number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create all combinations of columns names, then compare for not equal by `ne` and test if both are `True` by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and last count `True`s values by `sum` in list comprehension:

```
from  itertools import  combinations

out = [(', '.join(x),  df.loc[:, x].ne(0).all(1).sum()) for x in combinations(df.columns, 2)]
print (out)
[('ColA, ColB', 3), ('ColA, ColC', 3), ('ColB, ColC', 3)]

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['cols','count'])
print (df)
         cols  count
0  ColA, ColB      3
1  ColA, ColC      3
2  ColB, ColC      3
```

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanShahid - hmmm, what is your pandas version? Tested in pandas 0.25.0 and working nice

Comment: Yes i did already. I guess i am new and thats why its not appearing

Comment: I just encounter problem with the code above. For example: Col A is comparing with B and C but when it come to next column like column B then it compare only with C but i expect also that it compare with Column A also. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanShahid - So what are all combinations of columns `'ColA, ColB, ColC'` ?

Comment: In your output its showing [('ColA, ColB', 3), ('ColA, ColC', 3), ('ColB, ColC', 3)] but i expect this  [('ColA, ColB', 3), ('ColA, ColC', 3), ('ColB, ColA', 3), ('ColB, ColC', 3), ('ColC, ColA', 3), ('ColC, ColB', 3)]

Comment: It would be amazing if you can help me out

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanShahid - Use `permutation` like `from  itertools import  permutations

out = [(', '.join(x),  df.loc[:, x].ne(0).all(1).sum()) for x in permutations(df.columns, 2)]`